# Evaluating the indefinite integral $\int \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{4x^2 -1}}~dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find $$\int {x^3\over \sqrt{4x^2 -1}}\,dx.$$

---

Let
$2x = \sec u$, $2 =\sec (u) \tan(u) u^{'}(x).$  Then

$$
\begin{align*}
\int {x^3\over \sqrt{4x^2 -1}}\,dx &= \frac1{16}\int {\sec^3 u\over \tan u}\tan u \sec u \,  du\\
 &= \frac1{16}\int {\sec^4 u} \, du\\ 
&= \frac1{16}\left(\tan u + {\tan^3 u\over 3} \right) + C\\
 &= \frac1{16}\left(\tan (\sec^{-1} 2x) + {\tan^3 (\sec^{-1} 2x)\over 3} \right) + C. 
\end{align*}$$

Given answer : $$\dfrac{\left(2x^2+1\right)\sqrt{4x^2-1}}{24}+C$$

Why is my answer incorrect ?

Comment: I don't understand the second "$=$"

Comment: I canceled $\tan u$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac1{16}\sec^3x\int\sec udu$

Comment: @Giulio Sorry. that was a typo.

Comment: @DMcMor Thanks for the edit but I am not a big fan of using $dy/dx$.

Comment: One could also substitute $t=\sqrt{4x^2-1}$

Comment: @kingW3 The question asks me solve by trig substitution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:

$$\tan(\sec^{-1}(x))=\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

(that is, your answer simplifies a bit further)

Comment: For $ x > 0$. I know this but when I simplify with WA I don't get the answer :(.

Comment: Wait let me do that again by hand.

Comment: @A---B Yeah, I'm fairly sure it comes out right.

Comment: $$\frac1{16}\left(\sqrt{(4x^2 - 1)} + {(4x^2 - 1)^{3/2}\over 3} \right) + C$$

Yes got it.

Comment: @A---B $$(4x^2-1)^{3/2}=(4x^2-1)\sqrt{4x^2-1}$$

Comment: Yep. I did see that.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get to $\tfrac{1}{16}(\tan u + \tfrac{1}{3} \tan^3 u) + C$, get rid of $u$. Since $\sec u = 2x = 2x/1$, that means $\tan u = \sqrt{4x^2 - 1}$ (draw a right triangle to show this), so $$\begin{aligned}[t]\text{integral} = \tfrac{1}{16}(\tan u + \tfrac{1}{3} \tan^3 u) + C &= \tfrac{1}{16}\Big(\sqrt{4x^2 - 1} + \tfrac{1}{3} (4x^2-1)\sqrt{4x^2-1}\,\Bigr) + C \\ &= \tfrac{1}{16}\sqrt{4x^2-1} \, \Bigl(1 + \tfrac{4}{3} x^2 - \tfrac{1}{3} \Bigr) + C \\ &= \tfrac{1}{24}\sqrt{4x^2-1} \, \Bigl(2x^2+1 \Bigr) + C.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: corrected  my $u$'s.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan\left(\sec^{-1}(2x)\right)=\sqrt{4x^2-1}$$

Make this substitution into your answer and you will get the result you expected.

Comment: Thank you but the selected answer already pointed this out. I did not downvote.

Comment: You're right, I should have refreshed the page before posting.

Comment: No problem it happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your approach; you just need to fiddle around with trig identities to see that $\tan(\sec^{-1}2x)=\sqrt{\sec^2(\sec^{-1}2x)-1}=\sqrt{(2x)^2-1}$, etc.  But another, possibly easier, way to do the integral is to let $u=4x^2$ so that $du=8x\,dx$ and thus

$$\int{x^3\over\sqrt{4x^2-1}}dx={1\over32}\int{u\over\sqrt{u-1}}du={1\over32}\int\left(\sqrt{u-1}+{1\over\sqrt{u-1}}\right)du\\
={1\over48}(u-1)^{3/2}+{1\over16}(u-1)^{1/2}+C=\sqrt{u-1}\left(u+2\over48\right)+C\\
=\sqrt{4x^2-1}\left(4x^2+2\over48\right)+C=\sqrt{4x^2-1}\left(2x^2+1\over24\right)+C$$

Comment: Thank you but I don't think I am clever enough to figure out $${1\over32}\int\left(\sqrt{u-1}+{1\over\sqrt{u-1}}\right)du$$ :).

Comment: @A---B, think of the integrand as $(u-1)^{1/2}+(u-1)^{-1/2}$.  In general, one has $\int t^{r-1}\,dt={1\over r}t^r$, the one exception, of course, being when $r=0$.

Comment: Not the next but how did you get this integrand from previous step. Now I know how did you get that but I don't think I could have thought of this step will solving the problem.

Comment: @A---B, it takes time and practice to learn how to "see ahead" at what a substitution is likely to accomplish.  Now that you see how things worked out here, that may help later on.  And don't be afraid to try things that ultimately *don't* work out; you can learn a lot from failures, too.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{t \equiv \root{4x^{2} - 1} - 2x\ \mbox{and}\ x = -\,{t^{2} + 1 \over 4t}}$:
\begin{align}
\int{x^3 \over \root{4x^{2} - 1}}\,\dd x & =
{1 \over 128}\int{\pars{t^{2} + 1}^{3} \over t^{4}}\,\dd t
\end{align}

> Another one is
>   $\ds{y = x^{2} \implies {1 \over 2}\int{y \over \root{4y - 1}}\,\dd y}$.

Comment: Thank you but I need to solve by trig substitution, I should have mentioned it, my bad.

Comment: @A---B Anyway, it's other method you can keep for the future. The first one is one of the [Euler Substitution Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution). Thanks.

Comment: What other methods you know to solve integrals that does not require complex numbers ? I know trigonometric substitution, by parts and Euler substitution (You told me! thank you for that).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

By the above diagram, we can simplify the answer obtained by the author.
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\begin{aligned}
I &=\frac{1}{16}\left(\tan \theta+\frac{\tan ^{3} \theta}{3}\right)+C \\
&=\frac{1}{16}\left[\sqrt{4 x^{2}-1}+\frac{\left(4 x^{2}-1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right]+C
\\&=\frac{\sqrt{4 x^{2}-1}}{48}\left[3+4 x^{2}-1\right]+C \\
\\&=\frac{\left(2 x^{2}+1\right) \sqrt{4 x^{2}-1}}{24}+C
\end{aligned} \\
\end{array}
$$